# How to get a comma-separated list directly from table.Properties.VariableNames?

Tags: matlab

Example:

```
>> A = table({}, {}, {}, {}, {}, ...
             'VariableNames', {'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'Frobozz', 'Quux'});
>> vn = A.Properties.VariableNames;
>> isequal(vn, A.Properties.VariableNames)
ans =

 1
```

So far so good, but even though `vn` and `A.Properties.VariableNames` appear to be the same, they behave very differently when one attempts to get a "comma-separated list" from them (using `{:}`):

```
>> {'Frobnitz', vn{:}}

 ans = 

     'Frobnitz'    'Foo'    'Bar'    'Baz'    'Frobozz'    'Quux'

>> {'Frobnitz', A.Properties.VariableNames{:}}

 ans = 

     'Frobnitz'    'Foo'
```

Is there a way to get a "comma-separated list" from A.Properties.VariableNames *directly* (that is, without having to create an intermediate variable like `vn`)?

(Also, is there a more reliable function than `isequal` to test for equality of cell arrays?  In the example above `vn` and `A.Properties.VariableNames` are clearly *not equal enough*!)

---

For those who don't have a version of MATLAB that supports the (rather new) `table` objects, it's the same story if one uses `dataset` objects (from the Statistics toolbox) instead.  The example above would then translate to:

```
clear('A', 'vn');
A = dataset({}, {}, {}, {}, {}, ...
            'VarNames', {'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'Frobozz', 'Quux'});
vn = A.Properties.VarNames;
isequal(vn, A.Properties.VarNames)
{'Frobnitz', vn{:}}
{'Frobnitz', A.Properties.VarNames{:}}
```

(Note the change from `VariableNames` to `VarNames`; output omitted: it's identical to the output shown above):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem with `isequal`. `vn` and `A.Properties.VariableNames` are in fact equal. The problem is something else...

If you type `help dataset.subsref`, you will get an explanation of why this is happening which should be the same explanation as for the `table` class:

> LIMITATIONS:
>
> ```
>    Subscripting expressions such as A.CellVar{1:2}, A.StructVar(1:2).field,
>    or A.Properties.ObsNames{1:2} are valid, but result in subsref
>    returning multiple outputs in the form of a comma-separated list.  If
>    you explicitly assign to output arguments on the LHS of an assignment,
>    for example, [cellval1,cellval2] = A.CellVar{1:2}, those variables will
>    receive the corresponding values. However, if there are no output
>    arguments, only the first output in the comma-separated list is
>    returned.
> ```

In short, when you invoke the line `A.Properties.VarNames{:}`, you are making a call to the `dataset.subsref` method and the curly-brace subscript `{:}` is being passed to it right along with the other `.` subscripts, as opposed to being applied separately after the call to the `dataset.subsref` method.

Because of this, it doesn't look like you can get a comma-separated list directly from `A` without using an intermediate variable. However, if your goal (as in your example) is to concatenate the strings together with another string into a new cell array, you could do this:

```
>> [{'Frobnitz'} A.Properties.VarNames]

ans = 

    'Frobnitz'    'Foo'    'Bar'    'Baz'    'Frobozz'    'Quux'
```

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think there is anything you can do except create the temporary variable vn. It's long been a troubling shortcoming of user-defined classes that they cannot do comma separated list expansion. I do find it strange, though, that TMW chose to implement the `table` class in the user-defined class framework.

As for `isequal`, there is no issue there. The behavior you see has nothing to do with vn and A.Properties.VariableNames not being equal.